# Performance fluctuates as it is trained with DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning

[image: The game windowe]

I've trained a simple car game with DQN.

---

input : car's x coordinate, the obstacle's x,y coordinates

output : car's action

reward : when it successfully dodges.

penalty : when it crashes against walls or the obstacle.

---

NN Architecture :
1st hidden_layer_size : 100 (activation func. : relu)
2st hidden_layer_size : 50 (activation func. : relu)

Optimizer : Adamm with learning rate : 1e-6

Lost Func. : (Y - Y_var)^2

TARGET_NN_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000

epsilon decay : 1 to 0 with the rate of 0.99

---

RESULT :

- Reward_history (Reward is equivalent to a number of avoiding the obstacle)

[image: reward history]

Q. The performance fluctuates as it is trained. Strange to me. Although this game is not that complicated, it doesn't seem to find the ideal solution. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the learning rate?  I would also try decreasing the target update interval.

Comment: @BertKellerman Thank you so much :)  I think you got the point. Now that I look at them again, the learning rate might be too low and Target network update interval, too long. 
 I will try as you advised :) Thanks again!

Comment: @BertKellerman Yes! OMG. I was so surprised. Your advice totally worked. I changed learning rate from 1e-6 to 1e-4 and TARGET_NN_UPDATE_INTERVAL from 1000 to 100. It learned way more super faster..

Comment: Awesome!  I'm so glad it worked!